# Show CSV rows in reverse order with PHP

Tags: php

Trying to get this code to echo the rows it gets from the CSV file in reverse order. Any idea how to do this?

```
<?php
$row = 1;
$FILE = "file.csv";

if (($handle = fopen($FILE, "r")) !== FALSE) {

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);

        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            if ($c == 0) $first = $data[$c];
            if ($c == 1) $second = $data[$c];

        }

    }
    fclose($handle);

}
?>
```

Comment: Add rows to an array, [array_reverse](http://www.php.net/array_reverse), then output is one option. Another would be to write the output to a string, making sure to prepend on each iteration instead of appending then output.

Answer (score 4):

Create a specific function for this task and call the function. It is always easier to split your program into smaller pieces. You need to read the data into an array and the reverse the order.

```
<?php
function loadCSV($file) {
    $rows = array();

    if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            array_push($rows, $data);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

    return array_reverse($rows);
}
?>
```

Here is how to use this function:

```
<?php
$data = loadCSV('data.csv');
print_r($data);
?>
```

Comment: what if you have a very large file, read the whole file into memory?